# Configuring mysql datasource in javaee

Tags: jakarta-ee, datasource, glassfish-3

ok guys I know that it looks stupid as there are already many questions asked, but none of them is solving my problem for configuring a mysql datasource. I am using "Eclipse IDE", "MySql Database" and "java Language". I have configured context.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
 <Resource name="jdbc/world" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="admin" 
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world"/>
</Context>
```

and then web.xml as

```
<resource-ref>
<description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/world</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In the connection file name WorldCityBean.java I hava tried both ways i.e.

by annotating the class and by using InitialContext but it isn't working at all.

```
public class WorldCityBean {

@Resource(name="world")
private DataSource ds;

private Connection conn;

public void open() throws SQLException, NamingException{
    if(conn !=null)
    {
        return;
    }

//      Context ic = new InitialContext();
//      Context subcontext = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
//      DataSource ds = (DataSource) subcontext.lookup("jdbc/world");

    conn = ds.getConnection();
}
}
```

and giving this exeption

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from     fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection on     managed bean city

root cause 
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing     resource injection on managed bean city

root cause 
com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException:         com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to     inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: world@javax.sql.DataSource@ resolved as: jndi:     world@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties
Database Vendor : null
Create Tables at Deploy : false
Delete Tables at Undeploy : false into class com.corejsf.WorldCityBean

root cause 
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting     to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: world@javax.sql.DataSource@ resolved as:     jndi: world@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties
Database Vendor : null
Create Tables at Deploy : false
Delete Tables at Undeploy : false into class com.corejsf.WorldCityBean

root cause 
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/world' in             SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'world'     in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: world not found]]

root cause 
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'world' in SerialContext  [Root     exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: world not found]

root cause 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: world not found

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the     GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 logs.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using context.xml is not a standard way to configure JDBC resource in Glassfish. Although there are ways to configure it through deployment descriptor ([Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684583/what-is-the-glassfish-alternative-to-context-xml)), I would recommend using Web console. Log in, go to Resources and define Connection Pool and JDBC resource ([link for Glassfish 3.0.1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beamo/index.html)). If you do it that way, you can test/ping your SQL connection and check whether all parameters are correct. When you're sure that you have specified correct parameters, usual injection will be sufficient, but be careful - you have to specify:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/world")
```

instead of

```
@Resource(name="world")
```

Comment: Thanks @miljen mikic. Actually there were some problems by which it was not connecting and I figured it out. I removed the decalration/datasource definition from context.xml and web.xml. then I made the connection pool as described in [here](http://netbeans.dzone.com/connection-pooling-glassfish-nb) and followed the rest of tutorial. Thanks for your help, you gave me the actual string to pull over the rest.

Comment: @IConfused Yes, I was exactly referring to these steps, but you have found nice step-by-step tutorial. Glad to help.