# Server equivalent to application web.xml

Tags: servlets, glassfish, webserver, server-side-scripting

I'm running a .war file in 3 different Servers, but for each server I need a different description in the web.xml file, that will be accessed like:

```
context.getInitParameter("CompanyKey")
```

Is there a equivalent for a server file? It's being a pain to change this file at each deploy.

Im currently using GlassFish 4.1

Comment: For glassfish there is glassfish-web.xml http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaql.html

Comment: glassfish-web.xml is a parallel file to web.xml, right? I need a file that will placed in each server and accessible by my war file

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I found out that GlassFish holds a file called `default-web.xml` in the config folder.

All variables listed here  takes precedence over the variables in the application (war) `web.xml`.

I just transferred my variables there and it worked!

Some helpful links for those searching about `web.xml`, `context.xml` and `default-web.xml` (it helped me to get to my answer):

1. https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/how_to_use_tomcat_context
2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/geurd/index.html
3. [How can I share a variable or object between two or more Servlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123657/how-can-i-share-a-variable-or-object-between-two-or-more-servlets)
4. [What is the glassfish alternative to context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684583/what-is-the-glassfish-alternative-to-context-xml)